# numpy: evaluating function in matrix, using previous array as argument in calculating the next

Tags: performance, numpy, differential-equations, difference-equations

I have an `m x n` array: `a`, where the integers `m > 1E6`, and `n <= 5`.

I have functions **F** and **G**, which are composed like this: **F**( **u**, **G** ( **u**, t)). **u** is a `1 x n` array, t is a scalar, and **F** and **G** returns `1 x n` arrays.

I need to evaluate each `row` of `a` in **F**, and use previously evaluated row as the **u**-array for the next evaluation. I need to make `m` such evaluations.

This has to be really fast. I was previously impressed by `scitools.std` `StringFunction` evaluaion for a whole array, but this problem requires using the previously calculated array as an argument in calculating the next. I don't know if StringFunction can do this.

For example:

```
a = zeros((1000000, 4))
a[0] = asarray([1.,69.,3.,4.1])

# A is a float defined elsewhere, h is a function which accepts a float as its argument and returns an arbitrary float. h is defined elsewhere.

def G(u, t):
  return asarray([u[0], u[1]*A, cos(u[2]), t*h(u[3])])

def F(u, t):
  return u + G(u, t)


dt = 1E-6

for i in range(1, 1000000):
  a[i] = F(a[i-1], i*dt)
  i += 1
```

The problem with the above code is that it is slow as hell. I need to get these calculations done by numpy milliseconds.

How can I do what I want?

Thank you for our time.

Kind regards,

Marius

Comment: Your question doesn't fully make sense... If **u** is the previously evaluated row, then your formulas never make use of the current row. I am guessing that you mean something like **F**(**v**, **G**(**u**, t)), where **u** is the result of evaluating the last row, and **v** is the current row, but please confirm, and define how do you process the first row, where there is no "previously evaluated row" available. Also, and more important, without knowing what **F** and **G** do, I doubt anyone will be able to give you a satisfactory answer.

Comment: No, as far as I can tell, what I typed is what I want to do. I will add some more information.

Comment: Could you add code for a slow but correct implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is very difficult to do in numpy. If we look at this by column we see a few simpler solutions.

`a[:,0]` is very easy:

```
col0 = np.ones((1000))*2
col0[0] = 1                  #Or whatever start value.
np.cumprod(col0, out=col0)

np.allclose(col0, a[:1000,0])
True
```

As mentioned earlier this will overflow very quickly. `a[:,1]` can be done much along the same lines.

I do not believe there is a way to do the next two columns inside numpy alone quickly. We can turn to numba for this:

```
from numba import auotojit

def python_loop(start, count):
     out = np.zeros((count), dtype=np.double)
     out[0] = start
     for x in xrange(count-1):
         out[x+1] = out[x] + np.cos(out[x+1])
     return out

numba_loop = autojit(python_loop)

np.allclose(numba_loop(3,1000),a[:1000,2])
True

%timeit python_loop(3,1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.14 s per loop

%timeit numba_loop(3,1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 42.5 ms per loop
```

Although its worth pointing out that this converges to `pi/2` very very quickly and there is little point in calculating this recursion past ~20 values for any start value. This returns the exact same answer to double point precision- I didn't bother finding the cutoff, but it is much less then 50:

```
%timeit tmp = np.empty((1000000)); 
        tmp[:50] = numba_loop(3,50);
        tmp[50:] = np.pi/2
100 loops, best of 3: 2.25 ms per loop
```

You can do something similar with the fourth column. Of course you can `autojit` all of the functions, but this gives you several different options to try out depending on numba usage:

1. Use cumprod for the first two columns
2. Use an approximation for column 3 (and possible 4) where only the first few iterations are calculated
3. Implement columns 3 and 4 in numba using `autojit`
4. Wrap everything inside of an autojit loop (the best option)
5. The way you have presented this all rows past ~200 will either be `np.inf` or `np.pi/2`. Exploit this.

Comment: Second column can be np.cumprod([o0, A+1, A+1, ... ]). For the two others you would have to make custom ufuncs... But numba is a great suggestion! with numbapro you could even paralelize it :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly faster. Your first column is basicly 2^n. Calculating 2^n for n up to 1000000 is gonna overflow.. second column is even worse.

```
def calc(arr, t0=1E-6):
    u = arr[0]
    dt = 1E-6
    h = lambda x: np.random.random(1)*50.0

    def firstColGen(uStart):
        u = uStart
        while True:
            u += u
            yield u

    def secondColGen(uStart, A):
        u = uStart
        while True:
            u += u*A
            yield u

    def thirdColGen(uStart):
        u = uStart
        while True:
            u += np.cos(u)
            yield u

    def fourthColGen(uStart, h, t0, dt):
        u = uStart
        t = t0
        while True:
            u += h(u) * dt
            t += dt
            yield u

    first = firstColGen(u[0])
    second = secondColGen(u[1], A)
    third = thirdColGen(u[2])
    fourth = fourthColGen(u[3], h, t0, dt)

    for i in xrange(1, len(arr)):
        arr[i] = [first.next(), second.next(), third.next(), fourth.next()]
```